# Nodejs embedded image showing image in letter correctly but also as attachment

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am sending an email with nodejs trying to embed logo.png through CID to my letter but image show in letter correctly but also as attachment I don't want it appearing as attachment just in letter

```js
 let mailConfig = {
                        from: Testing,
                        html: doL,
                        subject: Testing,
                        to: email,
                        attachments: [
                            
                        {   // file on disk as an attachment
                             filename: 'logo.png',
                             path: 'logo.png',
                             cid: 'logo',
                         }
                        ]
                    };
```

```html
    <img src="cid:logo" height="50" width="180">
```

Comment: Upload the image somewhere then link it to the email. This avoids using attachments.

Comment: @JM-AGMS how do i use cid to call the image in letter?

Comment: If you use the CID then you'll always get attachments. You have to stop using CIDs completely and stop using attachments. Upload the image somewhere else, then link to it, like you normally would on a website: `<img src="https://example.com/image.png">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add: contentDisposition: 'inline'